# Cannot build jboss-eap-quickstarts 6.1.1

Tags: maven, jboss, maven-3

I would like to resolve dependencies for [jboss-eap-quickstarts](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts) project. I build it with `maven3`:

```
/usr/share/maven3/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn clean install
```

I received exception:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.bom:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:1.0.4.Final-redhat-9 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 76, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 92, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing. @ line 99, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for junit:junit:jar is missing. @ line 133, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar is missing. @ line 141, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar is missing. @ line 148, column 21
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 69, column 22
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 82, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 90, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 97, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 104, column 20
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 111, column 20
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing. @ line 118, column 19
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 68, column 25
//etc
```

The specified dependencies are missed in maven central.

**Question**: Should I look into another artifactory?

It isn't mentioned in a `readme` for the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add to your `pom.xml` file the following repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-developer-staging-repository</id>
        <url>http://jboss-developer.github.io/temp-maven-repo/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-developer-staging-repository</id>
        <url>http://jboss-developer.github.io/temp-maven-repo/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Especially the second one, `https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/`, contains the dependencies you are looking for, for instance [`jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools`](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/jboss/bom/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools/), the `1.0.4.Final-redhat-9` classified `pom`.

This is described in the `pom.xml` of its [`7.1`](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/blob/7.1.x-develop/pom.xml) development branch. However, there is no `6.1.1` branch and the `6.2.x` does not specify any repository indeed, but rather the set-up of a [local repository](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.2.x#configure-maven).